# Can I have a usb 3.0 adapter for PCI, my PC does not have extra PCI e port

Tags: usb, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

My problem is my motherboard has 2 PCI port and one PCI Express* x16 port. I really wish to have both usb 3.0 card adapter in my PC as well as a graphics card. It's very old, and I don't plan to get a new PC, I am trying to upgrade it.
Is there a graphics card which connects to PCI, and is it recommended that we can purchase and connect to PCI port? Or is there a usb 3.0 add on that can be connected to a PCI port (I don't think if it connects to PCI it will really be usb 3.0)

I want my OS installed on USB 3.0, for faster boot-up and privacy, ease of access, travel purpose. I wish I could get more out of my home PC, by having an graphics card, for obviously some gaming and handling video processing, is there any suggestions for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I have been in the exact same situation with a customer, this is my experience:

- First of all: Yes, you can
- Secondly: Don't do it

A bog-standard PCI slot provides around 120MByte/s (32Bit*33MHz-Overhead), which is just a fraction of what USB 3.0 can do - so you will by far not achieve the usual USB 3.0 speeds

In addition to that, PCI to USB 3.0 cards are a low-volume item, and as such they are quite pricey.

Alltogether: It's not worth it.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the BIOS could not boot from USB, and even if it could it would not be able to boot from a USB 3.0 drive on an add-in card.